# Show that multiplication operator $M_h$ is $M$-bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

Currently I am reading [Behrend's $M$-Structure and Banach-Stone Theorem](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540095330).
Behrend introduced $M$-bounded operator at page $55.$

> Let $T$ be an operator on a Banach space $X.$
>   $T$ is said to be *M-bounded* if there is a $\lambda>0$ such that for every $x\in X,$ $Tx$ is contained in every ball which contains $\{\mu x:\mu\in\mathbb{R}, |\mu|\leq \lambda\}.$

Note that 
$$\{\mu x:\mu\in\mathbb{R}, |\mu|\leq \lambda\} = \text{conv}\{-\lambda x,\lambda x\}$$
where $\text{conv}\{-\lambda x,\lambda x\}$ refers to the convex hull of two points $-\lambda x$ and $\lambda x.$

Let $Q$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $E$ be a Banach space. 
Behrend further introduced the multiplication operator on the function space $C_0(Q,E),$ the collection of all $E$-valued functions on $Q$ which vanish at infinity.

> For each $h\in C_0(Q),$ define *the multiplication operator* $M_h:C_0(Q,E)\to C_0(Q,E)$ by 
>   $$M_hf(s)=h(s)f(s), \quad \text{ for all }s\in Q.$$

Then Behrend proved the following lemma:

> **Lemma**:For each $h\in C_0(Q),$ the operator $M_h$ is $M$-bounded.

*Proof:* Let $\lambda = \|h\|_\infty.$ Fix $f\in C_0(Q,E).$ Pick $g\in C_0(Q,E)$ and $r>0$ such that 
$$\text{conv}\{-\lambda f,\lambda f\}\subseteq B(g,r)$$ 
where $B(g,r)=\{k\in C_0(Q,E): \|k-g\|_\infty\leq r\}.$
It is easy to verify that
$$M_hf\in B(g,r).$$
Therefore, $M_h$ is $M$-bounded.

> **Question:** How to show that 
>   $$M_hf\in B(g,r)?$$

The following is my 'unfinish' attempt:

If $M_hf\in\text{conv}\{-\lambda f,\lambda f\},$ then we are done. 
However, I think it is not true as 
$$M_hf=\frac{\|h\|-h}{2\|h\|}(-\lambda f) + \frac{\|h\|+h}{2\|h\|}(\lambda f)$$
where $h$ is not a scalar. 
I also tried to manipulate 
$$\|M_hf-g\|_\infty = \sup_{s\in Q}\|h(s)f(s)-g(s)\|,$$
but to no avail.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result holds due to the 'point-wise' nature of the supremum norm.
You have that 
$$
\|hf - g\|_\infty = \sup_{x\in Q} \| h(x) f(x) - g(x) \|_E \leq  \sup_{x\in Q}  \sup_{|\lambda'|\leq \|h\|_\infty} \| \lambda' f(x) - g(x) \|_E \leq r,
$$
where the last estimate holds since conv$\{-\lambda f, \lambda f\} \subset B(g,r)$ and $|\lambda'| \leq \lambda =  \|h\|_\infty$. Per definition this yields that $M_h f \in B(g,r)$.

I should clarify the reasoning behind the first inequality, by request in the comment.
First, we have that,
$$
\sup_{x\in Q} \| h(x) f(x) - g(x) \|_E \leq \sup_{x,y\in Q} \| h(y) f(x) - g(x) \|_E,
$$
which is clear, since $x,y\in Q$ includes $x = y$. Moreover, by assumption $\|h(y)\|_E \leq \|h\|_\infty$. Hence, 
$$
\sup_{x,y\in Q} \| h(y) f(x) - g(x) \|_E \leq \sup_{x\in Q, |\lambda'| \leq \|h\|_\infty} \| \lambda' f(x) - g(x) \|_E
$$
as claimed. The original notation was slightly missleading, so I changed it above.

Comment: May i know how to obtain second inequality? Furthermore, I think it is norm, not modulus.

Comment: I added some explanation on the first inequality. The second I believe is already sufficiently well explained, but there was an unfortunate choice of notation, which I improved. Hopefully, it is not clearer. I also replaced the modulus by the norm on $E$. Thank you very much.

Comment: I see. I think I need to go back to my basic analysis notes to revise my knowledge on supremum.